# Flutter: Update AppBar title from Streambuilder?

Tags: flutter

I'm populating a ListView from Streambuilder and want to show the length/nr of documents in the AppBar title. Right now I'm calling SetState everytime there's a change in the stream. It works but "feels" kinda resource heavy. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Best, 
/j

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
        appBarTitle = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
            setState(() {           
            });
        }); 
    },
);
```

Comment: You need to include your code to have an idea.

Comment: Hi Ian, thx, added code above. Best, /j

Comment: Can't the title be set to be the streambuilder when you create your appbar, does it produce some error (never tried, just wondering) ? Also does the Future.delayed get around some other problem for you ?

Comment: Use stream builder directly in appBar title . That way no need to call set state to update title.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give it a try. /j

Answer (score 3):

you can wrap title of appBar with Stream builder to update your screen title like this code

```
 AppBar(title: StreamBuilder<Object>(
    stream: bloc.myStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return yourCustomWidget();
    }
  )
```